# Как подвинуть текст внутри input'а?

Tags: html, css, input

Необходимо, чтобы текст не был за рамками `input'a`:

[image: само фото]

Comment: `padding`........

Comment: да,спасибо.помогло,вот только вместе с текстом и поле Input увеличивается

Comment: @fen1x потому что ширина жестко задана, на то количество что добавляете отступ отнимите в ширине

Comment: @entithat можете объяснить что такое "0" в нашем случае ?

Comment: @fen1x, `padding: <тут зачение по оси y> <тут значение по оси x>;`

Comment: @Alpha как понять : на то количество что добавляете отступ отнимите в ширине ??

Comment: @fen1x, имели ввиду, что если ширина Вашего инпута, допустим, 250, а padding Вы задали 10px, то задать ширину инпуту теперь не 250, а 240. Но какой-то пластмасовый способ ..

Comment: @entithat теперь всё понял)спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете добавить `padding'и` для отступа с края и воспользоваться свойством [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) со значением "border-box" для того что бы они "были включены" в основной размер:

```css
input {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #282928;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input value="text" />
```